# MongoDB Query in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I can not get VB.net connect to a mongodb replicaset - it throws exceptions

```
dim mongo as MongoDBClient
dim mgDB as MongoDatabase
dim mgcol as MongoCollection(of Bob)

public class Bob
   public property ID as ObjectID
   public property Name as string
end class

sub Main()
  try
    mongo = New MongoClient("mongodb://ip:port,ip:port,ip:port/?replicaSet=Bob")
    mgDB = mongo.GetDatabase("test")
    mscol = mgDB.Collection(of Bob)("test.me")

    mgDB.GetCollection("test.me").Find(MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Exists("id"))

catch ex as Exception
console.writeline(ex)
end try
end sub
```

I don't know how I'm supposed to query via VB .Net?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work

```
Dim _client As IMongoClient
Dim _db As IMongoDatabase

Sub Main()
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hi, Bob!!")

    Try

        _client = New MongoClient("mongodb://mongoone:27020,mongotwo:27021,mongothree:27020/?replicaSet=Bob")
        _db = _client.GetDatabase("Test")

        Dim mgCol = _db.GetCollection(Of Bob)("test.me")
        Dim mybob As Bob
        mybob = New Bob
        mybob.Name = "Sam6"
        mybob.ID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId

        'mgCol.InsertOne(mybob)

        getSomedata().Wait()
        'getDataByFilterExtists().Wait()
        'getMetaCardSpectrum().Wait()
        getMetaCardSpectrumObj().Wait()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try


End Sub
```